# Permission problem with files created by Deluge when one fstab entry was removed

Tags: server, permissions, nfs, smb, deluge

Recently my second hard disk, `sdb1`, broke on my Ubuntu server, it  was mounted as `multimedia` in `/home/user/multimedia` and Deluge is downloading my torrents to this directory.

When `sdb1` disk died, I removed the fstab entry:

```
UUID=4A3E87EC3E87CEFF /home/user/multimedia ntfs users,defaults 0 0
```

then used the `/home/user/multimedia` directory directly, making it `rwxrwxrwx`.

All seems to work fine, I can read and write from my iMac (same user credentials), Deluge can put files in the directory, and my TV can see the share, but every file that Deluge downloads has `rwxrwx---` permissions and my TV is not able to play them. If I put read permission for others users via chmod (`rwxrwxr--`), my TV plays all files correctly.

I don't know what changed from `multimedia` as mounted directory to real directory, but I want to avoid applying permissions with chmod to all files downloaded by Deluge.

Comment: Thank you karel for the answer, in effect before reading your post i found in '/etc/init/deluge.conf' the default umask setting of the deamon with 0007 value, i change to 0002 and now all works fine!! My mistery is why with my broken sdb1 and this configuration nothing of this appened, so for now this is good for me. Thanks again

Comment: I have checked my 'fstab'but what I've disabled is this string: 'UUID=4A3E87EC3E87CEFF /home/user/multimedia ntfs users,defaults 0 0' so i still curious to know what appened

Comment: So it was an `NTFS` formatted disk therefore I think the file permissions would default to `root` and `777` in the absence of any `umask`.

Comment: Yesss Cas!! This is the case! Thx again!

Comment: Please accept my answer: http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: for current Linux distros take a look at https://deluge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to/systemd-service.html

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the original mounted drive was an `NTFS` formatted disk therefore the file permissions would default to `root` and `777` in the absence of any `umask`.

The solution if you are running `deluged` as service is to modify the `umask` setting in the service config (e.g. `deluged.conf`).

Excerpt from deluge [upstart guide](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/Upstart#DelugeDaemondelugedJob):

```
You may wish to modify the above umask as it applies to any files downloaded by deluged.

 007 grants full access to the user and members of the group deluged is running as (in this case deluge) and prevents access from all other accounts.
 022 grants full access to the user deluged is running as and only read access to other accounts.
 000 grants full access to all accounts.
```

Comment: thx it's what i have done with 002